# matlab: minimization/optimization algorithm

Tags: matlab

I use function with multiple outputs `farina4` that computes coefficients `a`, `b`, `e`, `f` and a vector `out_p5tads_final` (1 x n array) through a minimization of a system of equations using the data input set  `p5tads` (1 x n array):

```
function  [a b e f fval out_p5tads_final] = farina4(p5tads)

f = @(coeff)calculs_farina4(coeff,p5tads);
[ans,fval] = fminsearchcon(f,coeff0,[0 0 0 0],[1 1 1 1]);% fminsearch with constrains
a = ans(1);
b = ans(2);
e = ans(3);
f = ans(4);

out_p5tads_final = p5tads_farina4(a,b,e,f);

function out_coeff = calculs_farina4(coeff0,p5tads)
    %bla-bla-bla
end

function out_p5tads = p5tads_farina4(a,b,e,f)
    %bla-bla-bla
end
end
```

After calculating `a`, `b`, `e`, `f` and `out_p5tads_final` I need to calculate/minimize the RMS function with respect to `out_p5tads_f4`.

```
RMS = sqrt(mean((p5tads(:) - out_p5tads_f4(:)).^2))*100
```

and to repeat function `farina4` in order to find the optimal set of the parameters `a`, `b`, `e`, `f` and `out_p5tads_final`.

I am trying to build up an algorithm of such optimization and do not see a way so far. 
For instance, it seems to be not possible to introduce a function with multiple output inside the above RMS equation unless there is a way to index somehow the output of this function `farina4`.
If there can be an alternative optimization algorithm for RMS without fminsearch (or similar) ?

a b e and f are values between 0 and 1
out_p5tads_final is an (1 x 10) array

```
%
function out_coeff = calculs_farina4(coeff0,p5tads)

%

mmmm = p5tads(1);

mmmr = p5tads(2);

rmmr = p5tads(3);

mmrm = p5tads(4);

mmrr = p5tads(5);

rmrm = p5tads(6);

rmrr = p5tads(7);

mrrm = p5tads(8);

mrrr = p5tads(9);

rrrr = p5tads(10);

%

a = coeff0(1);

b = coeff0(2);

e = coeff0(3);

f = coeff0(4);

%

f_mmmm = mmmm - ((a^2*b^2*(a + b) + e^2*f^2*(e + f))/2);

f_mmmr = mmmr - (a^2*b^2*(e + f) + e^2*f^2*(a + b));

f_rmmr = rmmr - ((a^2*f^2*(b + e) + b^2*e^2*(a + f))/2); 

f_mmrm = mmrm - 2*a*b*e*f;

f_mmrr = mmrr - b*f*(a^3 + e^3) + a*e*(a^3 + f^3);

f_rmrm = rmrm - 2*a*b*e*f;

f_rmrr = rmrr - 2*a*b*e*f;

f_mrrm = mrrm - ((a^2*b^2*(e + f) + e^2*f^2*(a + b))/2);

f_mrrr = mrrr - (a^2*f^2*(b + e) + b^2*e^2*(a + f));

f_rrrr = rrrr - ((a^2*f^2*(a + f) + b^2*e^2*(b + e))/2);

%

out_coeff = f_mmmm^2 + f_mmmr^2 + f_rmmr^2 + f_mmrm^2 + f_mmrr^2 + f_rmrm^2 + f_rmrr^2 + f_mrrm^2 + f_mrrr^2 + f_rrrr^2;

end

%
function out_p5tads = p5tads_farina4(a,b,e,f)

%

p_mmmm = ((a^2*b^2*(a + b) + e^2*f^2*(e + f))/2);

p_mmmr = (a^2*b^2*(e + f) + e^2*f^2*(a + b));

p_rmmr = ((a^2*f^2*(b + e) + b^2*e^2*(a + f))/2); 

p_mmrm = 2*a*b*e*f;

p_mmrr = b*f*(a^3 + e^3) + a*e*(a^3 + f^3);

p_rmrm = 2*a*b*e*f;

p_rmrr = 2*a*b*e*f;

p_mrrm = ((a^2*b^2*(e + f) + e^2*f^2*(a + b))/2);

p_mrrr = (a^2*f^2*(b + e) + b^2*e^2*(a + f));

p_rrrr = ((a^2*f^2*(a + f) + b^2*e^2*(b + e))/2);

%

out_p5tads = [p_mmmm,p_mmmr,p_rmmr,p_mmrm,p_mmrr,p_rmrm,p_rmrr,p_mrrm,p_mrrr,p_rrrr];

end

end
```

Thanks much in advance !

**19/08/2014   3:35 pm**

I need to get an optimal set of coefficients a b e f that the RMS value , which is calculated from

```
RMS = sqrt(mean((p5tads(:) - out_p5tads_f4(:)).^2))*100
```

is minimal. Here, the vector p5tads is used to calculate/optimize the set of a b e f coefficients, which are in turn used to calculate the vector out_p5tads_f4. The code should run a desired number of optimizations cycles (e.g. by default 100) and then select the series of a b e f and out_p5tads_f4 afforded the minimal RMS error value (with respect to out_p5tads_f4).

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to optimize? What is your objective function, ie what are 'the optimal set of the parameters a, b, e, f'?

Comment: see the above modification to the main question